# Input type time placeholder not showing in mobile browser

Tags: html, css

So in some cases I've heard that an input tag placeholder isn't supposed to work but in my desktop browser it does but for some reason it doesn't work in my mobile browser.

I want the placeholder to work in my mobile phone broser. If anyone could help me or find me an alternative to work a placeholder for input type time I'd really appreciate it

Here's a part of the code:

```html
<table class="sched--table">
    <form action="" method="post" id="theform">
    <tr><td><span class="orange trheader">Index</span></td><td><span class="orange trheader">Time ...</span></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#1</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_1" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_1')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#2</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_2" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_2')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#3</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_3" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_3')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#4</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_4" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_4')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#5</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_5" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_5')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#6</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_6" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_6')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>#7</td><td><input type="time" placeholder="Select Time.." id="sched_7" readonly="readonly" class="sched--input" step="0"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ClearDate('sched_7')" class="btn btn--s">Clear</a></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2">
                <input type="button"  class="btn btn--m btn--orange" value="Reset All" onclick="ResetAll();">
            <input type="button"  class="btn btn--m btn--orange" value="Save" onclick="SubmitForm('theform');">
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The input type time display:

[image]

After I clicked on it:

[image]

Comment: What's your desktop browser? Most likely, it displays in browsers that do not support `time` input elements thus default to `text`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Its Edge. And the mobile one is safari

Comment: My Edge doesn't. Is it possible you're still using the legacy non-Chromium Edge, which didn't support `input="time"`? https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_time

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I checked it in Mozilla and Chrome. The placeholder is displaying for both

Comment: I just need it to show it in my mobile browser, its not working there

Comment: I'm just speculating that the reason it works in certain browser may be that it's obsolete. If that's the case, the only option would be getting an older phone 

Comment: While it is true that browsers (at least nowadays) take no notice of the placeholder attribute (I've tested on Windows 10 Edge/Chrome and Firefox and on IOS14 Safari) what I don't understand is why you are expecting the user to be able to select a time when you have readonly set. Could you describe a bit more what you are wanting? Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth I've added the display output in the post. I want the `Select time..` placeholder to show in my mobile browser but its missing. Basically its a time set feature

Comment: Hi, placeholder just doesn't work in (most?) uptodate browsers. You will need to do something like have a label which tells the user what to do rather than a placeholder. What browser and what version are you using that is letting you put in a placeholder? And why are you setting readonly (which gives the current time?) but asking them to select a time?